# Bootstrap menu agrego li active class onclick

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente menú de arranque

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li class="active">

        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".menu-nav" class="collapsed drop-down" aria-expanded="false">Link1<span class="caret"></span></a>

        <ul id="menu-nav" class="nav menu-nav collapse" aria-expanded="false">

          <li> <!-- tambien agrega active -->

            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapsed" data-target=".menu-navs" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Sub Link1<span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul id="menu-nav" class="nav menu-navs collapse" aria-expanded="false">

              <li> <!-- tambien agrega active -->

                <a href="javascript:;" class="collapsed" data-target=".menu-navss" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Sub1 Link1<span class="caret"></span></a>

                <ul id="menu-nav" class="nav menu-navss collapse" aria-expanded="false">

                  <li><p>Test Ok</p></li>

                </ul>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

        </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

¿cómo puedo alterar el agrego de la "< li >" clase de activo cuando se hace clic en cualquiera del < li > ?

La siguiente no está funcionando para mí

```
$("li").on("click",function(){
  $(".nav navbar-nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://jsfiddle.net/cs7qw44n/#&togetherjs=8rQckJ7ICy

Comment: ¿casa o trabajo? No aparecen de esa forma.

Comment: trabajo, por que no?

Comment: me refiero a que tu pregunta dice `¿cómo puedo alterar el cambio de la "< li >" clase de activo cuando se hace clic en cualquiera de casa o del trabajo?` pero no hay ninguna etiqueta que diga casa o trabajo

Comment: me equivoque. solo se hace clic en cualquier de <li>

Comment: El título de la pregunta parece un telegrama y a mi me parece difícil de comprender.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes Probar

```js
$(function() {
  
  // elementos de la lista
  var menues = $(".nav li"); 

  // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
  menues.click(function() {
     // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
     menues.removeClass("active");
     // activamos el elemento clicado.
     $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo siempre van a quedar con la clave Active los que están abiertos. ya que si le quitas el activo se cerrara automáticamente por motivos del bootstrap.

la única forma de que se visualice sin la clase active es que no uses las clases de bootstrap y dispares el menu con jquery UI que seria open.